# selenium gives an error the second time in the while loop

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I get an error message after running the code below.
This works fine for the first time in the while loop.
For some reason, it crushes for the second time in the while loop...
How can I make this work?

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

game_mins = 5
play_seconds = 5

chrome_driver_path = "your own chrome driver address here"
ser = Service(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser)

driver.get("http://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/")

cookie = driver.find_element(By.ID, "cookie")

Most_expensive = driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyTime machine")
Second_expensive = driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyPortal")
Third_expensive = driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyAlchemy lab")
Fourth_expensive = driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyShipment")
Fifth_expensive = driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyMine")
Sixth_expensive = driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyFactory")
Seventh_expensive = driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyGrandma")
Eighth_expensive = driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyCursor")

game_end = time.time() + game_mins * 60

while time.time() < game_end:
    t_end = time.time() + play_seconds
    while time.time() < t_end:
        cookie.click()

    print("Moving on to the ifs statement")
    time.sleep(4)

    if Most_expensive.get_attribute("class") != "grayed":
        print("Time machine purchased")
        Most_expensive.click()
    elif Second_expensive.get_attribute("class") != "grayed":
        print("Portal purchased")
        Second_expensive.click()
    elif Third_expensive.get_attribute("class") != "grayed":
        print("Alchemy lab purchased")
        Third_expensive.click()
    elif Fourth_expensive.get_attribute("class") != "grayed":
        print("Shipment purchased")
        Fourth_expensive.click()
    elif Fifth_expensive.get_attribute("class") != "grayed":
        print("Mine purchased")
        Fifth_expensive.click()
    elif Sixth_expensive.get_attribute("class") != "grayed":
        print("Factory purchased")
        Sixth_expensive.click()
    elif Seventh_expensive.get_attribute("class") != "grayed":
        print("Granma purchased")
        Seventh_expensive.click()
    else:
        print("Cursor purchased")
        Eighth_expensive.click()

time.sleep(50)
```

This is the error message I got on the console. As you can see, I did not get the message "Factory purchased", which I would have expected to see on the console.

```
Moving on to the ifs statement
Granma purchased
Moving on to the ifs statement

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: 
Message: unknown error: 
unhandled inspector error: 
{"code":-32000,"message":"No node with given id found"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element was supposed to have gone stale and a StaleElementReferenceException was expected since you are continously clicking and DOM keeps on changing but instead 'unhandled inspector error' is being thrown seems like a possible bug with chrome 113 [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4440)

Try it like below should work fine for you

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

game_mins = 5
play_seconds = 5

chrome_driver_path = "your own chrome driver address here"
ser = Service(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser)

driver.get("http://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/")

cookie = driver.find_element(By.ID, "cookie")

game_end = time.time() + game_mins * 60

while time.time() < game_end:
    t_end = time.time() + play_seconds
    while time.time() < t_end:
        cookie.click()

    print("Moving on to the ifs statement")
    time.sleep(4)

    if driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyTime machine").get_attribute("class") != "grayed":
        print("Time machine purchased")
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyTime machine").click()
    elif driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyPortal").get_attribute("class") != "grayed":
        print("Portal purchased")
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyPortal").click()
    elif driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyAlchemy lab").get_attribute("class") != "grayed":
        print("Alchemy lab purchased")
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyAlchemy lab").click()
    elif driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyShipment").get_attribute("class") != "grayed":
        print("Shipment purchased")
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyShipment").click()
    elif driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyMine").get_attribute("class") != "grayed":
        print("Mine purchased")
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyMine").click()
    elif driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyFactory").get_attribute("class") != "grayed":
        print("Factory purchased")
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyFactory").click()
    elif driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyGrandma").get_attribute("class") != "grayed":
        print("Granma purchased")
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyGrandma").click()
    else:
        print("Cursor purchased")
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "buyCursor").click()

time.sleep(50)
```